# ReactJS: Jest coverage report of untested files shows 0% coverage

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, code-coverage, jestjs, istanbul

I tried testing code coverage of untested source js files of my React application using jest but was shocked to see that it mostly gave 0% code coverage for all files. Is it fine to test code coverage of `component.js` files of React using Jest or am I doing anything incorrect here.

Here is my jest configuration specified in package.json:

```
  "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "collectCoverageFrom" : ["**/src/**/*.js"]
  }
```

my coverage snapshot:

[image: coverage report]

I don't believe that 0% of my code statements are executing for all files. Any thing I am missing here? Is this report fine for es6 app? I even tested the code coverage of react boilerplate app created using react cli create-react-app by ejecting webpack. Even the boilerplate app shows code coverage as 0% for untested js files. This is 100% false. Any idea on this results?

Answer (score 1):

Note, that *collectCoverageFrom* need provide with *collectCoverage* as Jest [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#collectcoveragefrom-array) told us:

> This option requires collectCoverage to be set to true or Jest to be invoked with --coverage